# $|x^{-1}-y^{-1}|=|x-y|/|x||y|$ in a normed ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, continuity, absolute-value, noncommutative-algebra

I hit a slight snag when trying to prove that the inverse function $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ on the unit group is continuous in a ring with an absolute value, so I'd like some confirmation that the theorem is in fact true.

Here's a version of the classical proof that reciprocal is continuous on $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$:

> Let $x\ne 0$ and $\epsilon>0$, and let $\delta=\dfrac{|x|}2\min(1,\epsilon|x|)$. Now suppose $y\ne0$ and $|x-y|<\delta$. Then $$|y|\ge|x|-|x-y|>|x|-\delta\ge\frac{|x|}2,$$ so $|x-y|<\delta\le\dfrac{|x|}2\epsilon|x|<\epsilon|xy|$. Thus $\epsilon>\dfrac{|x-y|}{|xy|}=\left|\dfrac {x-y}{xy}\right|=\left|\dfrac1x-\dfrac1y\right|$.

Most of this proof is interpreted easily in an arbitrary ring with an absolute value (replacing "$x\ne0$" with "$x$ is a unit"), but I can't complete the final step. We have $|xy||x^{-1}-y^{-1}|=|xyx^{-1}-xyy^{-1}|=|xyx^{-1}-x|$, but there seems no reason to believe that this is equal to $|y-x|$ unless I assume the ring is commutative.

Is it true that the reciprocal function in a normed ring is continuous? What if we assume that the ring is a division ring?

**Edit:** By "normed ring" or "ring with an absolute value" I am referring to [Absolute value (algebra)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value_%28algebra%29), which is to say a map $|\cdot|:R\to\Bbb R$ satisfying $|x|=0\iff x=0$, $|x-y|\le|x|+|y|$, $|xy|=|x||y|$.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps this comment is off base, but even in metrizable groups the inverse operation is not necessarily continuous. Are you certain that it should work here?

Comment: @CameronWilliams No I'm not, but then again in the group case even commutativity doesn't solve the problem. Just because my proof failed doesn't mean that it's not true, and I don't know any other theory in this area (I'm just writing down reasonable-looking statements and trying to prove them).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key here is that the real numbers form a commutative ring. Therefore 
$$
|xy||x^{-1} - y^{-1}| = |x||y||x^{-1} - y^{-1}| = |x| |x^{-1} - y^{-1}||y| = |xx^{-1}y - xy^{-1}y| = |y-x|. 
$$
(P.S. I assumed that by normed ring you meant [Banach algebra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_ring), which puts an inequality ; I only put equality because you did. Was I correct? If the answer is not helpful please take the time to add a definition.)

Hope that helps,

Comment: I do not mean a Banach algebra, that's rather more structure than I have (although somehow I doubt that any of it would come into play in a proof here). OP edited to clarify.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Ahhh. I didn't know these were called normed rings, but I know absolute values. Then my proof is fine!

Comment: Oh, wait, yeah that's totally valid. Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: This doesn't really answer whether or not it can be done in a non-commutative setting though.

Comment: @CameronWilliams : Did you see me use commutativity of the ring? I only used commutativity of real numbers.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yes it does, even for a non-commutative ring we have $|xy|=|x||y|=|y||x|=|yx|$ because $\Bbb R$ is commutative.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I totally misunderstood what you meant by the commutativity of $\mathbb{R}$. I thought you were working in $\mathbb{R}$. My bad!

Comment: @CameronWilliams : It happens! No worries.